# Partial Derivatives vs Implicit Differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is:

Let $G(x,y)=x^2y^4-3x^4y$.

(i) Find the first partial derivatives $G_x$ and $G_y$.

(ii) Using (i) above, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

(iii) If $G(x,y)=0$, confirm your answer in part (ii) above, finding $\frac{dy}{dx}$ using implicit differentiation.

Comment: What work have you done so far on the problem?

Comment: I edited your question.  Please review my changes to make sure I did not inadvertently change the content of your question.

Answer (score 3):

The chain rule says:
$$
dG = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}dy.
$$
If the point $(x,y)$ moves along a level set of $G$, then we have $dG=0$.  Hence
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-\partial G/\partial x}{\phantom{-}\partial G/\partial y}.
$$
$$
= -\frac{2xy^4 - 12x^3 y}{x^2 4y^3 -3x^4}
$$
and then we can cancel an $x$.

Now let's try implicit differentiation:
$$
x^2y^4 - 3x^4y = 0.
$$
$$
2x y^4 + x^2 4y^3 \frac{dy}{dx} - 12x^3y - 3x^4\frac{dy}{dx} =0.
$$
Push the two terms not involving the derivative to the other side; then pull out the common factor, which is the derivative; then divide both sides by the other factor.  We get
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{12x^3y - 2xy^4}{x^24y^3 - 3x^4}
$$
and it's the same thing.